# create ~ dir in another dir mistakenly, can not delete it

Tags: linux

I mistakenly create `~` in `~/source`

```
sx@ubuntu:~/source$ pwd
/home/sx/source
sx@ubuntu:~/source$ ll
total 440
drwxr-xr-x  3 sx sx   4096 2012-12-06 02:25 ~
drwxr-xr-x  4 sx sx   4096 2012-12-06 02:25 ./
drwxr-xr-x 47 sx sx   4096 2012-12-06 02:26 ../
```

I don't dare to delete it using command `rm ~`, because it may lead to deleting all my file in home dir.

Comment: In your case you can use **rm -r "./~"** but I've posted more general solution.

Comment: This has been answered before: http://superuser.com/questions/609362/have-a-file-named-tilde-in-my-home-directory-linux

Answer (score 2):

There is general solution to delete files with uncommon names: first you need to know file's inode number, then you can delete it with **find** command

```
$ mkdir "~"
$ ls -i
>28972221 ~
$ find -inum 28972221 -delete
```

Answer (score 1):

As always, specify the path.

```
rmdir ./~
```