# Have a file named ~ (tilde) in my home-directory

Tags: linux, bash, filesystems

I just noticed that I have a file called `~` in my `~`-directory.

```
$ ls -la ~
...
-rw-r-----  1 x1 x1  733962240 Mar  1 17:55 ~
...
```

Any idea how I can `mv` or `rm` it?

Comment: Try to delete it by i-node.

Answer (score 58, accepted):

The pretty much ultimate solution when it comes to files that can't be deleted by normal means:

```
ls -il
```

The first column will show the inode number of the files.

```
find . -inum [inode-number] -exec rm -i {} \;
```

This will delete the file with the specified inode-number after verification.

Comment: This worked. Perhaps the the solution by rici is good too, but I didn't try. Thanks a lot!

Comment: Yes, rici's answer is good too. And I think it's better because it's simpler.

Comment: nice, +1. I changed your answer to use `-delete` instead of `-exec`, then realized that you were using `rm -i` which is a good idea so I rolled back. Sorry.

Comment: Don't worry. Always glad when somebody deems my answers worthy of their time :)

Comment: This answer didn't work for me. Ubuntu 14.04 LTS

Comment: The answer worked, but the tilde directory kept being re-created by eclipse. Had to clear the tilde out of the default workspace in eclipse/configuration/.settings/org.eclipse.ui.ide.prefs

Answer (score 52):

You should be able to refer to that file as `~/~` (without quotes) because tilde-expansion only applies the the tilde (`~`) at the very beginning of the word.

Comment: also, going to the folder and `rm ./~`, for the same reason you said

Comment: @CarlosCampderrós consider making that an answer. I would deem it as the "best" and most straightforward solution, compared to other answers since `./~` literally means **"a file or folder named `~` in the current directory"**. There are no hacks like escape characters or inode references.

Comment: @ADTC: in defence of my answer, it does not require changing the CWD, whereas using `./~` does. After five years, my memory is a little fuzzy, but I think that is why I suggested `~/~` rather than the more normal `./~`: The question specifically refers to "a file named `~` in [OP's] **home directory**"; not "in the current directory".

Comment: @rici That makes sense, and in the context of the question it would be appropriate. But I do like to see answers that are general, or speak generally first before expounding more to the question's specific case. That's my defense :D

Answer (score 20):

Quote it (`rm '~'`) or escape it (`rm \~`).

---

It's always either of those (also for e.g. `$`), or add `--` to prevent the file name from being interpreted as argument: `rm -- -i` removes the file named `-i`; also useful for `rm -- *` when you want to delete all files in the current directory: No accidental `rm -f *` just because a file is named like that.

Comment: Hm, no that doesn't seem to work.. I tried the single quotes, the escaping and backticks.. he doesn't pick up the file. Says either it doesn't exist or interprets ~ as the home-directory..

Comment: @scrrr What's your shell?

Comment: bash. But problem solved the inode way.

Comment: @scrrr Glad your problem is solved,  but  now I want to know why bash escapes don't work the same way on your system as it does on mine.

Comment: Careful. `--` only stops the following arguments being interpreted as parameters - it doesn't prevent the shell from performing its expansion (e.g. `*`), which is what's happening here. (I know you suggested it as an alternative for other situations, but a warning would be good.)

Comment: @Bob Well, `rm -- *` does what it says on the tin (what else would you expect?). You won't accidentally `rm -f *` though, just because there's a file named `-f`.

Comment: It's a nuance that those unfamiliar with shell expansion might make a mistake with. I'm just suggesting making that a bit clearer in the answer.

Answer (score 1):

Just to be safe I tried this in mac catalina:

**mv '~' '~_bkp'**

you can change directory to check the contents

**cd '~_bkp'
ls**

If its empty simply 'remove'

**rm -rf '~_bkp'**

'rmdir' can be used too to remove the empty directory