# Extra "~" symbol in ls command in unix

Tags: linux, ubuntu-14.04

In my home directory, I now have this:

```
service@myComp:~$ pwd
/home/service
service@myComp:~$ ls -l
total 44
drwxr-x---  3 service service 4096 Mar 21 16:03 ~
drwxrwxr-x  4 service service 4096 Dec 27 11:17 backups
drwxrwxr-x  3 service service 4096 Mar 21 17:56 bashScripts
...
```

However, ~ is not a file. I can `cd ~` but that just brings me back to my home directory. How can I safely delete it? Not even sure how it go there...

This is in Ubuntu 14.04

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Have a file named ~ (tilde) in my home-directory](http://superuser.com/questions/609362/have-a-file-named-tilde-in-my-home-directory)

Comment: @SeanClt: This was different, I had a directory. Similar but when I searched, I didn't find it.

Comment: google found it for me it happens, that other questions looks more extensively discussed, i would recommend reviewing that as well you might find more meaningful information on that discussion

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`~` by itself is a special character that gets replaced with you home directory when shell is doing path expansion.

In your case you have a directory named `~`, so to access it you must escape the character with backslash or quotes.

Try:

```
cd \~
rmdir \~
```

to enter the directory and remove it (if it was empty).

It is possible that some (misconfigured) program or script uses this directory for storing its files, so check before deleting.